# Android Studio compilation error with same package in differents modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I have a problem when I try to compile a project in android studio with the following structure:

```
PROJECT
 MODULE_A
    |_ com.project.moduleA
       ...
 MODULE_B    
    |_ com.project.moduleB
       |_ view
          |_ Example.java    
 MODULE C
    |_ com.project.moduleB
       |_ dto
          |_ Pepe.java
    |_ com.project.moduleC
       ...
```

The compilation throws this error:

```
package com.project.moduleB.dto does not exist
cannot find symbol class Pepe
```

I have the same package in modules B and C, and I try to access to class Pepe from class Example.
I have rebuilt, cleaned, refreshed the project many times and I still not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you add them properly to the dependencies?

Comment: @AvinashJoshi I have added this in buid.gradle from MODULE_B module: `dependencies {
   compile project(':MODULE_C')
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my project has a configuration for Proguard on the moduleC , so, I added the following line:

```
-keep class com.myproject.moduleB.** { *; }
```